# Can't find field (List of custom POJOs) in Thymeleaf?

Tags: spring, thymeleaf

I have the following code below. Thymeleaf is unable to resolve "orderDetails" despite the field being existent/not null when i debug through the internals of Thymeleaf.

Exception=  Field or property 'orderDetails' cannot be found on object of type

```
<div th:each="order : ${orders}">
 <table>
      <tr>
        <th>CUSTOMER</th>
        <th>PRICE</th>
        <th>TIME ORDER PLACED</th>
        <th>ITEMS</th>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td th:text="${order.customerAccount.email}">email</td>
        <td th:text="${order.baseCost}">2.50</td>
        <td th:text="${order.tip}">2.00</td>
        <td th:text="${order.orderDetails}">2.00</td>
       <!--  <td th:text="${#lists.size(order.orderDetails)}">1</td> -->
      </tr>

    </table>

     <table>
      <tr>
        <th>DRINK NAME</th>
        <th>AMOUNT</th>
        <th>QUANTITY</th>
        <th>COST</th>
      </tr>

      <tr th:each="orderDetail : ${order.orderDetails}">
        <td th:text="${orderDetail.barStock.drink.name}">Test Drink Name</td>
        <td th:text="${orderDetail.barStock.amount}">10oz</td>
        <td th:text="${orderDetail.quantity}">2</td>
        <td th:text="${orderDetail.barStock.cost * orderDetail.quantity}">2.00</td>
      </tr>

    </table>
```

Here is the field in question of the "order" field/class.

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "barOrder")
@JsonProperty
private Set<OrderDetail> orderDetails;
```

Comment: Do you have public getter method for orderDetails field?

Comment: /facepalm ... nooooooo :X

Comment: Feel free to put that as an answer so that I can give you credit.

Comment: I have posted my comment as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A public getter method for orderDetails field is needed to allow Thymeleaf to access it.

```
public Set<OrderDetail> getOrderDetails() {
  return orderDetails;
}
```